# How do I get detect a pattern including an arbitrary string?

Tags: java, regex

I have a response system, and I'm trying to get it so you can input a String, and it matches it to the most likely String in its database by looping through each one and measuring the Levinshtein Distance with predefined questions and using a few other algorithms.

Example: If you input "Hi, how are you?" It will search its database for something identical or very similar (like "Hi, how are you doing?"). But I want it to be able to detect if a specific phrase that depends on the circumstances is being used, such as:

"Give me 10 cookies." Now, I don't want to add all possible numbers of cookies in the database. That would be impossible. So, in the database, it would be something like:

"Give me [number] cookies." How would I detect the pattern though? Keep in mind I'm also going to be using String patterns for other responses.

Answer (score 2):

Library? [Apache Lucene Core](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) with its [FuzzQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/FuzzyQuery.html).

Comment: Thank you. So, how would I be able to use FuzzyQuery as a CSG parser?

Comment: Add [lucene-core](http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.apache.lucene%22%20AND%20a%3A%22lucene-core%22) as dependency to your Maven POM.

Comment: I did that, I just mean how do you search for a pattern?

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't know. I've never used it. I just knew it exists for that when you were asking for libraries.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible using regular expressions to solve this problem. Regular expressions represents [regular grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar) you need a [context-sensitive grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar) parser for this purpose.

Comment: Hmm. Any Java examples? Libraries? :I

Comment: Lucene with fuzzy query looks ok, but I can't tell you more than you can find by yourself with some research.